# TypeError: slideArr[0] is undefined on carousel using *ngFor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have been trying to search what I'm doing wrong, maybe you can help me.

I'm trying to display a carousel using ***ngFor="let image of card.carouselImgs"**  on the ngb-carousel template like this:

```
 <ngb-carousel>
     <template *ngFor="let image of card.carouselImgs" ngbSlide  >
       <img src="{{image.imgUrl}}" alt="{{image.imgAlt}}">
     </template>
   </ngb-carousel>
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: slideArr[0] is undefined
Stack trace:
NgbCarousel.prototype._getNextSlide@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43189:9
NgbCarousel.prototype.cycleToNext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43149:76
NgbCarousel.prototype._startTimer/this._slideChangeInterval<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43174:67
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3176:17
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4326:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3175:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2943:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3238:28
timer@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:4433:17
```

So I checked if it was something wrong with the data, but is not, everything works fine when doing this:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of card.carouselImgs">
  imgUrl: {{image.imgUrl}} 
  imgAlt: {{image.imgAlt}}
</div>
```

Output:

```
imgUrl: ../../assets/briefcase/1.jpg imgAlt: Hello
imgUrl: ../../assets/briefcase/2.jpg imgAlt: Hello
imgUrl: ../../assets/briefcase/3.jpg imgAlt: Hello
```

So I think is an error from ngb-carousel. Any help?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move ngFor from ng-template

may be like that:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let image of card.carouselImgs">
      <ng-template ngbSlide>....</ng-template>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. ng-template must be used instead of template tag?

Comment: template  is deprecated in Angular4. Use ng-template  in angular 4. please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say anything definitive without a clear reproduce scenario but one thing to notice is that you *must* use `<ng-template>` element with the latest (`1.0.0-alpha.25` at the time of writing) release of https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

So your example would translate to:

```
<ngb-carousel>
     <ng-template *ngFor="let image of card.carouselImgs" ngbSlide  >
       <img src="{{image.imgUrl}}" alt="{{image.imgAlt}}">
     </ng-template>
   </ngb-carousel>
```

Here is a plunker forked from the [demo page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel) showing things working with `<ng-template>`: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ec6OwwxCEawWNVaqEpk?p=preview - you might want to fork this plunker to provide clear reproduce scenario and expand your question if needed.